# Runtime error using MLFlow and Spark on databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, mlflow

Here is some model I created:

```
class SomeModel(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def predict(self, context, input):
        # do fancy ML stuff
        # log results
        pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(...insert predictions here...)
        spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
        spark_df.write.saveAsTable('tablename', mode='append')
```

I'm trying to log my model in this manner by calling it later in my code:

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="SomeModel_run"):
    model = SomeModel()
    mlflow.pyfunc.log_model("somemodel", python_model=model)
```

Unfortunately it gives me this Error Message:

`RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.`

The error is caused because of the line `mlflow.pyfunc.log_model("somemodel", python_model=model)`, if I comment it out my model will make its predictions and log the results in my table.

Alternatively, removing the lines in my predict function where I call spark to create a dataframe and save the table, I am able to log my model.

How do I go about resolving this issue? I need my model to not only write to the table but also be logged

Comment: Why do you need to write from the model into a table?

Comment: we want to log the results of our ML algo

Comment: How do you invoke your model? Rest api?

Comment: Yeah, which is why we need to log the model to then register it

Comment: Have you figured this out yet @ghostiek? I'm facing a similar issue

Comment: Decided to just say screw registering models and instead creating a job using the notebook. Its more pricey though as you need a full compute cluster. Still open to finding a proper solution though.

Comment: That is a shame. I'll give you an update if I find the solution.

Comment: note that I did try also using DBFS and alter files but since it's hosted somewhere else I wasn't able to access the path. I think I also looked into connecting to Databricks API to send a request to read/write to a file to log results but that also fell through as I needed to create a .netrc file to login and there was no way I was going to put my databricks login/password on a registered model. [DBFS API Doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs.html) [Auth Doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and I was able to resolve this by taking spark functions like "spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)" outside of the class. If you want to read-write data using spark do it within the main function.

```
    class SomeModel(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
       def predict(self, context, input):
       # do fancy ML stuff
       # log results
       return predictions

    with mlflow.start_run(run_name="SomeModel_run"):
      model = SomeModel()
      pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(...insert predictions here...)
      mlflow.pyfunc.log_model("somemodel", python_model=model)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if we use model serving. It will work in a notebook but otherwise this won't work if we use the model as an endpoint